# Is there any implementation of immutable maps in JavaScript that isn't 2 orders of magnitude slower than native objects?

Tags: javascript

I've micro-benchmarked a simple sequence of insertions and lookups comparing Immutable.js and native objects:

#### Immutable.js

```
var L = 1000000;
var m = Map();
for (var i = 0; i < L; ++i) {
  m = m.set(i,i);
}
var s = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < L; ++i) {
  s += m.get(i);
}
console.log(s);
```

#### Native object

```
var L = 1000000;
var m = {};
for (var i = 0; i < L; ++i) {
  m[i] = i;
}
var s = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < L; ++i) {
  s += m[i];
}
console.log(s);
```

Seems like Immutable.js is 100x slower. I've also attempted [my own implementation](https://gist.github.com/MaiaVictor/44f8a305cef34b285c911e28dfccd398) using Patricia Trees, but it was slower still. I wonder if there is any way to implement an immutable map of int keys to arbitrary values that is faster, or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the number of iterations. Fixed.

Comment: Are the keys arranged sparsely or do they really exist from `0` to `1000000` without holes in practice? If they're not sparse, I'd suggest using a native `Array`. If they _are_ sparse, this probably isn't a very representative benchmark to begin with.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think this benchmark is ok-ish because inserting random keys didn't alter the performance on my tests. Keeping it from 0 to 1000000 was useful for testing the lookup performance. But perhaps a better test would be to just insert random key/vals and not benchmark the lookup since it is not the bottleneck anyway. But yes, the keys are supposed to be sparse and random on the actual application, otherwise I'd just use arrays.

Comment: What's your reason for not using native `Map`?

Comment: Specifically, is it a functional purity thing or do you actually need this to solve a problem best solved as far as you know with immutable maps? If it’s the latter, maybe there’s an alternative approach to the broader problem?

Comment: `m = m.set(i,i)` assigning is not required. Just `set` call is enough

Comment: @Ry- the specific problem is speeding up the code when compiling [Formality](https://github.com/moonad/formality) - a pure functional language - to JavaScript, so no workaround here.

Comment: @adiga true, thank you.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts because assigning to a native Map immutably is even slower as it requires copying all key/val pairs.

Comment: @MaiaVictor I didn't say "immutably", just at all.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've asked right on the title for an implementation of immutable maps, so I think it was clear the structure couldn't be mutable.

Comment: I am not aware of any implementations, but note that Immutable.js is faster for certain use cases, such as lazy evaluation.